# Book recommendation about Factor Analysis

Tags: inference, references, factor-analysis

Hello StackExchange community, I'd like to study some concepts related to varimax rotation, Average variance extracted, Kaiser-Meyer-Olkin, Bartlett's test, ...

Do you know a book where I can learn about them?

Answer (score 1):

**Mulaik ["Foundations of Factor Analysis"](https://www.routledge.com/Foundations-of-Factor-Analysis/Mulaik/p/book/9781420099614) (2009)**. 2nd edition, Routledge.
This is a deep, technical book based on an algebraic perspective (which could be contrasted to, say, a probabilistic perspective). It includes a lot of historical notes explaining the development of the ideas in addition to their technical aspects.
The focus is mostly on exploratory FA, less on confirmatory FA.

**Klein ["Principles and Practice of Structural Equation Modeling"](https://www.guilford.com/books/Principles-and-Practice-of-Structural-Equation-Modeling/Rex-Kline/9781462523344) (2015)**. 4th edition, Guilford Press.
A few chapters in the book deal with exploratory and confirmatory FA, mostly the latter. This is less technical than Mulaik (2009) and quite readable, but still covers most of the important details.